# How to simulate click event for a link using Qt with python

Tags: python, pyqt, web-crawler

I want to screen scrape a web site having multiple pages. These pages are loaded dynamically without changing the URL.

I dont want to use Selenium since it opens browser every time you need content.Does QT work the same way?If not, how can i simulate click event using qt?

PS:Google provided vague answer
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's already a project that does just that: [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). It uses PyQt4's or PySide's QWebkit browser internally.

Here's their example code:

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost()
page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://jeanphi.fr")

assert page.http_status==200 and 'jeanphix' in ghost.content
```

You will most likely be using `ghost.click()` to interact with your webpage:

```
ghost.click('#selector')
```

Comment: I tried your example..it is saying - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'http_status'..could u help me please..

Comment: Same: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'http_status'... why is every headless python browser impossible to implement on windows?

Comment: @Amalgovinus: I can't reproduce your problem, so I'm not sure what isn't working.

Comment: It's almost as if the framework can't phone out on my machine.